# looping through files and data error message pandas python

Tags: python, loops, pandas

I have an excel file:

```
data = pd.read_excel('.../excel.xlsx')

VHseqName    VHseq      
  nameA       
  nameB
  nameC
  nameD
  nameE
  nameF
....
```

i have a fasta file :

```
f=open(".../Fastafile.fasta", "r+")

>nameA
AAAGGGCCT
>nameC
GGTTAACC
>nameD
CCCTTAA
>nameF 
GGGGGAATTCC
....
```

my desired output is: (for every match of the name from excel and fasta, put the sequence which is the next line to the same row but for column 'VHseq')

```
  VHseqName    VHseq      
  nameA       AAAGGGCCT
  nameB
  nameC       GGTTAACC
  nameD       CCCTTAA
  nameE
  nameF       GGGGGAATTCC
....
```

my code:

```
for vh in data["VHseqName"]:

position = data.index.get_indexer_for((data[data['VHseqName'] == vh].index)) 

   for line in f:
     title = line[1:]
     title = title.rstrip()   
     seq = f.readline()
        if(title in vh):
          data['VHseq'][position] = seq
          break
```

my code works sometimes, and sometimes it doesn't give complete result table, and i get this error each time:

**A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame
See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-   docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
data['full_H_Sequence'][position] = seq**

i looked into it and played around with the code and changed to (as suggested by comments below)

```
data.loc[:,('full_H_Sequence',position)] = seq
```

but this time i got this error message:
**return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence**

what's the right syntax to use here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The explanation at [that link](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy) was pretty helpful. It looks like the solution is to use `data.loc[:,('VHseq', position)] = seq` . The problem seems to be that the first `[]` returns a singly indexed data frame, which you can't necessarily just update.

Comment: this time the error gives:     return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order) ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence